# Cleaning up javascript code to avoid nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, promise

I have a bunch of chained jquery events, using .then to ensure proper order of execution:

```
function openWindow(book_section_id) {
    //do some stuff
    return newWindow
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    newWindow = openWindow(5);
    newWindow.onload = function(){
    $.when(newWindow.getStudentHighlightsAjax).done(function(){
    getText(5);
})  
.then(function() {
    newWindow.close();
    newWindow = openWindow(12);
    newWindow.onload = function() {
        $.when(newWindow.getStudentHighlightsAjax).done(function() {
            getText(12);
        }).then(function() {
            newWindow.close();
        });};
    });};
});
```

In my final chain, I'm going to have about 20 or 30 "thens", and I'd like to clean things up by creating a function that will execute:

```
newWindow = openWindow(x);
newWindow.onload = function() {
$.when(newWindow.getStudentHighlightsAjax).done(function() {
    getText(x);
});
```

The problem is that each subsequent .then is "wrapped up" in the previous onload event (notice that the "{" doesn't get closed until the end of my script.  My question is whether there might be a way to re-write the code so that I can have something more along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    process(5).then(process(12);
});
```

Comment: I think this: is missing a bracket.. 
process(5).then(process(12));

Comment: `process(5).then(process(12))).then(process(666));` can be used if process method return a promise (ajax request) or a deferred object. I'm just stuck reading your code and trying understand what you are currently doing here

Comment: Store all the functions in a list (Array), create a recursive function and set a counter.

Comment: Basically, I'm opening a new window, waiting for some ajax to complete from that window, then grabbing the text from that window.  I do this for several different webpages as defined by "book_section_id" (5, 12, etc.).  And though it works, it's exactly the "not so clear" aspect that I was hoping to fix!

Comment: Derek, I've never used recursion before.  Would you be able to show a very basic example (not necessarily with what I'm doing) so I can get a better feeling for the process?

Comment: @Eric If you return a promise from `.then` it will resolve with the value of that promise and you avoid nesting - this is the piece you're missing in the puzzle. Returning promises from `then` handlers is the key.

Comment: Why not just move the `getStudentHighlightsAjax` call into the `openWindow` function and return the promise, seems like you're repeating code for no apparent reason ?

Comment: Benjamin, thank you for the comment.  And, truth be told, this is the first time that I'm using $.when (i.e. my first deferred object).  Would you be able to show an example of this?  And, I'd prefer to figure out the details as it relates to what I'm doing, so just a hint would be great.

Comment: @Eric If you want a good introduction I suggest you read https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970 . Chaining and exception handling are the two major strengths of promises. If you find yourself nesting it means your'e not chaining probably.

Comment: Great!  I'll do that.  Is there anyway that I can count your comment as my accepted answer?

Comment: @Eric I've posted in the promises chat room asking for an answer, I've also re-tagged it as [tag:promise] so SO promise people like Bergi might come here :) I don't have time to write a proper answer right now but I promise that if none of them answer in a few hours I'll write my own answer. You should wait for a good answer :)

Comment: Thanks again!  And, I'm pretty excited about exploring this programming concept.  Though I only have a fuzzy understanding at the moment, I already have a sense of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert `onload` to promises immediately:

```
function whenLoaded(newWindow) {
  if (newWindow['-onload-promise']) 
    return newWindow['-onload-promise'];
  var d = $.Deferred()
  newWindow.onload = d.resolve.bind(d, newWindow);
  return newWindow['-onload-promise'] = d.promise();
}
```

Now you can use it in your promise chain.

Edit: ready() doesn't return a promise, so I had to nest that part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  whenLoaded(openWindow(5)).then(function(newWindow) {
    return $.when(newWindow.getStudentHighlightsAjax);
  }).then(function() {
    // ...
  })
})
```

Comment: This is exactly the structure that I was hoping for.  And, I began reading Learning JQuery Deferreds by Terry Jones since I last checked this post.  With that said, I'm getting the error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" when I run the script.  And, I'm pretty sure that the issue is that the newWindow object is somehow not getting passed back.  Any additional thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's the error using Firefox's Firebug: TypeError: $(...).ready(...).then is not a function
}).then(function(newWindow) {    so it looks like the error occurs on the .then(function(newWindow) line

Comment: I guess that ready() doesn't return a promise then. You will have to nest all the rest within it.

Comment: Thanks for you help!  And, as a final question, do you have any personal favorites (either on the web or in text form) for helping someone to get started with understanding Deferreds better?

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use a library like AsyncJS ( https://github.com/caolan/async ) or JSDeferred ( http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/ ) and use something like in the example:

```
async.series([
function(){ ... },
function(){ ... }
]);
```

Ensuring all the calls are executed sequentially?

Comment: There is no need to include an additional library to do this.

Comment: JSDeferred is exactly the same as jQuery promises only older, an additional dependency, and worse.

Comment: not all additional dependencies are bad.. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery, I've used this in my project, and it works pretty well with whatever I have

Comment: I prefer Bluebird to Q (better stack traces, much faster) but the general statement is correct :)